# match part of string but exclude certain file extension

Tags: regex

I have following two files:

```
test_ExampleSchemeConfig
test_ExampleSchemeConfig.cpp
```

and I want to use the following regular expression to separate these two. I want
to filter out `test_ExampleSchemeConfig` and the following expression doesn't work:

```
test_.*(?!(\.(cpp|hpp)))$
```

I'm wondering how can I fix it?

I believe answer to my question should be somewhere but I have no luck finding it.

Thanks much!

Comment: Do you want to match the first one only? If not, use [`test_.*$(?<!\.[ch]pp)`](https://regex101.com/r/JnUAnr/1) (or [`^(?!.*\.[ch]pp$)test_.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/JnUAnr/2)). If you want to match a part before the extensions, try [`(test_.*?)(?:\.[ch]pp)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/JnUAnr/3) and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I want to match the first one only. Definitely not the second one. I use this regular expression as a filter to the unwanted files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using one of the following regular expressions:

```
^test_[^.]*$
```

It will match a string starting with `test_`  and then having any 0+ chars other than `.`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2JPXq/2).

Or, you may use

```
^test_.*$(?<!\.[ch]pp)
```

It will match any string starting with `test_` and then having any 0+ chars, but not ending with `.cpp` or `.hpp`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2JPXq/1).

If your regex engine does not support lookbehind, use the equivalent pattern with a lookahead:

```
^test_(?!.*\.[ch]pp$).*$
```

This regex matches `test_`, then makes sure there are no 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with `.`, `c` or `h` and then `pp` at the end of the string, and then grabs the whole line. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2JPXq/3).